# Splitting words in a selected file

Tags: c#, strings, comparative-review

I'm at loggerheads between performing operations one-by-one within a method, performing all of them at once (in one block) within the method, or breaking them up into four different methods.

In terms of best-practice, which of the following three options seems most advantageous, and why would it be preferred over the other options?

### 1st Option

Call the code:

```
string filename = string.Empty;
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No file selected - exiting");
    return;
}
SpacelessWordBreakAerator(filename);
```

Implementation of code:

```
    private void SpacelessWordBreakAerator(string filename)
    {
        string soughtCombo = string.Empty;
        string desiredCombo = string.Empty;
        List<string> specialWordEndings = new List<String>();
        specialWordEndings.Add("é");
        specialWordEndings.Add("í");
        specialWordEndings.Add("ñ"); 
        specialWordEndings.Add("?");
        specialWordEndings.Add("!");
        specialWordEndings.Add(",");
        specialWordEndings.Add(".");
        specialWordEndings.Add(":");
        specialWordEndings.Add(";");
        specialWordEndings.Add("\"");
        specialWordEndings.Add("»");
        specialWordEndings.Add("ß");
        List<string> specialWordBeginnings = new List<String>();
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("¿");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("¡");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("\"");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("«");

        // Aerate "special" combinations:
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                foreach (string endChar in specialWordEndings)
                {
                    foreach (string beginChar in specialWordBeginnings)
                    {
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", endChar, beginChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", endChar, beginChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }
                }
                document.Save(); // Save after each step
            }
            // Aerate "special" ending with "normal" beginning - create a new DocX object with each different logic block
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                foreach (string endChar in specialWordEndings)
                {
                    for (int i = FIRST_CAP_POS; i <= LAST_CAP_POS; i++)
                    {
                        char upperChar = (char)i;
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", endChar, upperChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", endChar, upperChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }
                }
                document.Save();
            }
            // Aerate "normal" ending with "special" beginning
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                for (int i = FIRST_LOWER_POS; i <= LAST_LOWER_POS; i++)
                {
                    char lowerChar = (char)i;
                    foreach (string beginChar in specialWordBeginnings)
                    {
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", lowerChar, beginChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", lowerChar, beginChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }
                }
                document.Save();
            }
            // Aerate "normal" combinations (this is the legacy "InsertSpaceBetweenLowercaseAndUppercaseChars" helper method)
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                for (int i = FIRST_LOWER_POS; i <= LAST_LOWER_POS; i++)
                {
                    char lowerChar = (char)i;
                    for (int j = FIRST_CAP_POS; j <= LAST_CAP_POS; j++)
                    {
                        char upperChar = (char)j;
                        string originalStr = string.Format("{0}{1}", lowerChar, upperChar);
                        string newStr = string.Format("{0} {1}", lowerChar, upperChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(originalStr, newStr);
                    }
                }
                document.Save();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("SpacelessWordBreakAerator() finished! Aintcha glad?!?");
    }
```

### 2nd Option

Call the code:
(same as first option)

Implementation of code:

```
    private void SpacelessWordBreakAerator(string filename)
    {
// same var and const declarations as in first option...

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
// Keep using the DocX object until the end, and save it only after all operations have completed
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                // Aerate "special" combinations:
                foreach (string endChar in specialWordEndings)
                {
                    foreach (string beginChar in specialWordBeginnings)
                    {
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", endChar, beginChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", endChar, beginChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }
                }

            // Aerate "special" ending with "normal" beginning
                foreach (string endChar in specialWordEndings)
                {
                    for (int i = FIRST_CAP_POS; i <= LAST_CAP_POS; i++)
                    {
                        char upperChar = (char)i;
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", endChar, upperChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", endChar, upperChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }

            // Aerate "normal" ending with "special" beginning
                for (int i = FIRST_LOWER_POS; i <= LAST_LOWER_POS; i++)
                {
                    char lowerChar = (char)i;
                    foreach (string beginChar in specialWordBeginnings)
                    {
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", lowerChar, beginChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", lowerChar, beginChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }

            // Aerate "normal" combinations (this is the legacy "InsertSpaceBetweenLowercaseAndUppercaseChars" helper method)
                for (int i = FIRST_LOWER_POS; i <= LAST_LOWER_POS; i++)
                {
                    char lowerChar = (char)i;
                    for (int j = FIRST_CAP_POS; j <= LAST_CAP_POS; j++)
                    {
                        char upperChar = (char)j;
                        string originalStr = string.Format("{0}{1}", lowerChar, upperChar);
                        string newStr = string.Format("{0} {1}", lowerChar, upperChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(originalStr, newStr);
                    }

                }
                document.Save();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("SpacelessWordBreakAerator() finished! Aintcha glad?!?");
    }
```

### 3rd Option

Call the code:

```
string filename = string.Empty;
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No file selected - exiting");
    return;
}
// Break it up into four separate methods
SpacelessWordBreakUnusualCombo(filename);
SpacelessWordBreakUnusualEndNormalBegin(filename);
SpacelessWordBreakNormalEndUnusualBegin(filename);
SpacelessWordBreakNormalCombo(filename);
```

Implementation of code:

```
    private void SpacelessWordBreakUnusualCombo(string filename)
    {
        string soughtCombo = string.Empty;
        string desiredCombo = string.Empty;
        List<string> specialWordEndings = new List<String>();
        specialWordEndings.Add("é");
        specialWordEndings.Add("í");
        specialWordEndings.Add("ñ"); 
        specialWordEndings.Add("?");
        specialWordEndings.Add("!");
        specialWordEndings.Add(",");
        specialWordEndings.Add(".");
        specialWordEndings.Add(":");
        specialWordEndings.Add(";");
        specialWordEndings.Add("\"");
        specialWordEndings.Add("»");
        specialWordEndings.Add("ß");
        List<string> specialWordBeginnings = new List<String>();
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("¿");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("¡");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("\"");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("«");

        // Aerate "special" combinations:
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                foreach (string endChar in specialWordEndings)
                {
                    foreach (string beginChar in specialWordBeginnings)
                    {
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", endChar, beginChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", endChar, beginChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }
                }
                document.Save(); // Save after each step
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("SpacelessWordBreakAerator() finished! What a relief!");
    }

    private void SpacelessWordBreakNormalBeginUnusualEnd(filename)
    {
        string soughtCombo = string.Empty;
        string desiredCombo = string.Empty;
        List<string> specialWordEndings = new List<String>();
        specialWordEndings.Add("é");
        specialWordEndings.Add("í");
        specialWordEndings.Add("ñ"); 
        specialWordEndings.Add("?");
        specialWordEndings.Add("!");
        specialWordEndings.Add(",");
        specialWordEndings.Add(".");
        specialWordEndings.Add(":");
        specialWordEndings.Add(";");
        specialWordEndings.Add("\"");
        specialWordEndings.Add("»");
        specialWordEndings.Add("ß");

        // Aerate "special" combinations:
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            // Aerate "special" ending with "normal" beginning
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                foreach (string endChar in specialWordEndings)
                {
                    for (int i = FIRST_CAP_POS; i <= LAST_CAP_POS; i++)
                    {
                        char upperChar = (char)i;
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", endChar, upperChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", endChar, upperChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }
                }
                document.Save();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("SpacelessWordBreakAerator() finished! Ah, the beauty of it all!");
    }

    private void SpacelessWordBreakUnusualBeginNormalEnd(filename)
    {
        string soughtCombo = string.Empty;
        string desiredCombo = string.Empty;
        List<string> specialWordBeginnings = new List<String>();
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("¿");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("¡");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("\"");
        specialWordBeginnings.Add("«");

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                for (int i = FIRST_LOWER_POS; i <= LAST_LOWER_POS; i++)
                {
                    char lowerChar = (char)i;
                    foreach (string beginChar in specialWordBeginnings)
                    {
                        soughtCombo = string.Format("{0}{1}", lowerChar, beginChar);
                        desiredCombo = string.Format("{0} {1}", lowerChar, beginChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(soughtCombo, desiredCombo);
                    }
                }
                document.Save();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("SpacelessWordBreakAerator() finished! Oh, wonderful day!");
    }

    private void SpacelessWordBreakNormalCombo(filename)
    {
        string soughtCombo = string.Empty;
        string desiredCombo = string.Empty;

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
            {
                for (int i = FIRST_LOWER_POS; i <= LAST_LOWER_POS; i++)
                {
                    char lowerChar = (char)i;
                    for (int j = FIRST_CAP_POS; j <= LAST_CAP_POS; j++)
                    {
                        char upperChar = (char)j;
                        string originalStr = string.Format("{0}{1}", lowerChar, upperChar);
                        string newStr = string.Format("{0} {1}", lowerChar, upperChar);
                        document.ReplaceText(originalStr, newStr);
                    }
                }
                document.Save();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("SpacelessWordBreakAerator() finished! Happy happy joy joy!");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `.add()` so many times? Why not go `List<string> specialWordEndings = new List<String>(){"a","b","c"};`?

Comment: Good point; that would be better form.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? Your update suffers from the very same problems, which I gave you a complete solution for.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use names like `Popul8` and `DuckbilledPlatypus` in production code..

Comment: @DanAbramov: I always use "Popul8"; why not? As for the other, I work for a foundation for the preservation of Duckbilled Platypi, an endangered species in some parts of the word - thus, why wouldn't I use it?

Comment: I meant "world," of course - not "word."

Comment: I changed the real code to use the more terse form of adding strings to the generic string list; there's no pressing need to do it with all the code here.

Comment: Ah, platypus makes sense then, sorry! Why write `Popul8` when you can write `Populate`? As for the rest—you asked for a review, and there are still issues in your code (namely, code repetition and useless `int` -> `char` conversions). I'm not sure why you don't want to fix those, especially if I gave you working code for that. Anyway, that's up to you of course.

Comment: As to not using "Popul8": I do not wear a tuxedo when I code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd take the last option and then extract common functionality between

- `SpacelessWordBreakUnusualCombo`
- `SpacelessWordBreakNormalBeginUnusualEnd`
- `SpacelessWordBreakUnusualBeginNormalEnd`

and other methods into a single method that accepts parameters.

On the glance, they look *too* similar so it should be just one method.

If I'm not mistaken, it should look like this:

```
private void ReplaceTextInFile(string filename, IDictionary<string, string> replacementMap)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    try
    {
        using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
        {
            foreach (var replacement in replacementMap)
            {
                document.ReplaceText(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
            }

            document.Save();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

All your methods seem to be special cases of this method, with different `replacementMap` parameter.

Then create a method to build a `Dictionary<string, string>` representing **all** replacements you'll ever need:

```
    private static readonly List<string> SpecialWordBeginnings = new List<string> { "¿", "¡", "\"", "«" };
    private static readonly List<string> SpecialWordEndings = new List<string> { "é", "í", "ñ", "?", "!", ",", ".", ";", "\"", "»", "ß" };

    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> ReplacementMap = BuildReplacementMap();

    private static IDictionary<string, string> BuildReplacementMap()
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var ending in SpecialWordEndings)
        {
            foreach (var beginning in SpecialWordBeginnings)
            {
                result.Add(
                    ending + beginning,
                    ending + " " + beginning
                );
            }

            for (var uppercaseChar = 'A'; uppercaseChar <= 'Z'; uppercaseChar++)
            {
                result.Add(
                    ending + uppercaseChar,
                    ending + " " + uppercaseChar
                );
            }
        }

        for (var lowercaseChar = 'a'; lowercaseChar <= 'z'; lowercaseChar++)
        {
            foreach (var beginning in SpecialWordBeginnings)
            {
                result.Add(
                    lowercaseChar + beginning,
                    lowercaseChar + " " + beginning
                );
            }

            for (var uppercaseChar = 'A'; uppercaseChar <= 'Z'; uppercaseChar++)
            {
                result.Add(
                    string.Concat(lowercaseChar, uppercaseChar),
                    lowercaseChar + " " + uppercaseChar
                );
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Also note that you can do `for` on `char`s directly, no need to convert from `int`.

Since the replacement map is always the same, it is better to compute it once and store in a static field (which I did).

Finally, pass the map to our first method:

```
ReplaceTextInFile(filename, ReplacementMap);
```

Comment: I would move `specialWordEndings` and `specialWordBeginnings` to class static variables.  This will save on memory and time when instantiating the class.

Comment: The map is data, and should probably be coming from a config file/database.  Otherwise, spot on.

Comment: @jmoreno: I stand by generating it though. If the map itself came from database, it would *not* be trivial to add one more word beginning or ending (or e.g. support Cyrillic characters). Generating it preserves the logic and shows the intent.

Comment: @DanAbramov: I was referring to `SpecialWordBeginnings` and `SpecialWordEndings`.  How much effort would be involved in adding "@" to `SpecialWordBeginnings`...

Comment: @jmoreno: Got it, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a change to the top level logic to address the following issues.

- Don't read/write the file multiple times.
- Make it easy to add new DocX transformers.
- Make each transformer an explicit class.

I would make a DocXTransformer class something like below.

```
public class DocXTransformer
{
    private DocX document;

    public DocXTransformer(string filename)
    {
        document = DocX.Load(filename);
    }

    public void Transform(IEnumerable<ITransformer> transformers)
    {
        foreach( var transform in transformers)
        {
            document = transform.Execute(document);
        }
        document.Save();
    }
}
```

Creating the DocXTransformer will load the file.
Calling Transform, will execute a list of Transformer classes, which each implement the ITransform interface.

```
public interface ITransformer
{
    DocX Execute(DocX document);
}
```

I think this make the different logic parts separate and you will get cleaner code, where it's going to be easy to add a new transformer, while still paying some attention to performance.

Comment: It may be a good direction but until we know for sure there that are different kinds of transforms, this sounds like a premature generalization to me. Still, +1.